# Restrict characters used in a string

Tags: php, scripting, string

How do I restrict a string to whitelisted characters?

```
// "HOW am I to understand; this is, BAD"

$str = restrictTo($str,"0-9a-z,. ");

// " am I to understand this is, "
```

Is there an inbuilt function in PHP that does something close? I can't formulate a regular expression for this though :(

Comment: What should the result be? Should it strip out all of the characters that aren't allowed? Should it return false if non-allowed characters are included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, If you just want to replace characters, use [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/preg_replace) (Note, you can add any character with a few caviats.

1. If you want to add `-`, it MUST be at the end of the list
2. If you want to add a `\`, it MUST be escaped by another `\`
3. If you want a `/`, `[` or `]`, it must be escaped by a `\`)

This allows certain characters and filters out the rest:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z,.]/', '', $str);
```

If you want to reject any string that has any character that doesn't match:

```
if (preg_match('/[^A-Za-z.,]/', $str)) {
    //Rejected String
}
```

Comment: How do I filter out spaces? or allow spaces to remain in the string?

Comment: If you only want literal spaces, you can add `\040` for the character class (after the `.`).  If you want all white space characters (including new lines, tabs, etc) you can add `\s`.  For more info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.backslash.php